# How do you compare a column in two worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone tell me how to compare only one column instead of the whole sheet?
thank you.

Sub Compare()

```
 Call compareSheets("Sofon", "Sofontest")

 End Sub


Sub compareSheets(Sofon As String, Sofontest As String)

Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sofontest).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sofon).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

         mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
         mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sofontest).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to compare one column instead of the whole sheet, you should specify that in the For Each Loop.
Instead of .UsedRange use .Range("Col:Col"), where Col is the column you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

```
Call compareSheets("Sofon", "Sofontest", "B1:B900")

End Sub


Sub compareSheets(Sofon As String, Sofontest As String, sRange as String)

Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sofontest).sRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sofon).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

         mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
         mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation


End Sub
```